# DynamoDB Conditional Checks on Arrays of Strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, set, conditional-statements, amazon-dynamodb

Can I check if part of an element exists in an Array of Strings, or check if multiple elements exist in one query? So:

1) Does an element start with `'aaa:'` in the array `['aaa:1', 'bab:0', 'aab:1']`

2) Does the element `'aaa:1' OR 'aaa:0'` exist in the array `['aaa:1', 'bab:0','aab:1']`

If so, do not execute the API operation.

Is this possible? The Documentation isn't clear if UPDATE_ITEM is this robust or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: NO for both

The long answer is:

- Point 1) will never be possible
- Point 2) can be done using the **CONTAINS** filter of the **scan** operation but... only for a single match. No "OR" stuff. However, scan is both *slow* and *expensive* and thus heavily discouraged.

UPDATE_ITEM conditions will only allow exact matches.